# AWK reference columns from file based on header of the columns

Tags: shell, awk

I have the following code in cmd.awk:

```
 BEGIN {FS=","}
 {
    if(FNR==1) print $0",Header";
    else if (FNR>1)
            {
                    if($79==0 && $80==0 && $81==0) print $0",0";
                    else if ($80==0 && $81!=0) print $0","($79-$81)/$81;
                    else if ($81==0 && $80!=0) print $0","($79-$80)/$80;
                    else if ($81==0 && $80==0 && $79!=0) print $0",10";
                    else if ($81!=0 && $80!=0) print $0","(($79-$80)/$80)+(($80-$81)/$81);
            }
}
```

When i execute the following commamnd:

```
awk -f cmd.awk input.txt
```

it performs the required operation(as specified in the AWK Script) and provides the required result.

But in this script all the columns of the input txt file are being accessed based on the column_index i.e., $79, $80, $81 etc.

My requirement is that i need to use this script as a function which takes $79, $80, $81 and Header(as given in the script) as parameters, performs operations and stores result in the newly appended column with column name Header and store the new contents into an output file. But i am only allowed to specify the parameters in the form of column headers and not in column index i.e., my function call has to be something like this:

```
cmd(column_header1, column_header2, column_header3,new_header)
```

and the function definition of cmd() has to perform the operation mentioned in the awk script above.

Is there any way to do this? Please bear in mind that I'm very new to awk. Thanks in advance.

My input file contains 150 columns and over 50M rows. A sample of the file is given below:

```
RN,DATE,ID,PRE_M1,PRE_M2,GALV,GALG,PRE_M5.........................TOTAL
0624873840,2016/04/28,201610,1618,0,0,0,Active,.................12234
0747269250,2016/02/02,201610,227,93,0,0,Daat,....................99988
```

The input file contains columns of type numeric,character. The columns being accessed in the above AWK script are all of type numeric.

A sample of the required output file is as below:

```
RN,DATE,ID,PRE_M1,PRE_M2,GALV,GALG,PRE_M5.........................TOTAL,Header
0624873840,2016/04/28,201610,1618,0,0,0,Active,.................12234,10
0747269250,2016/02/02,201610,227,93,0,0,Daat,....................99988,0
```

Please note that a new column is being appended to the file with name "Header" and this column contains the result of the AWK script for each individual row of the input file.

Comment: in your sample file don't add 80+ columns, 4-5 columns should be sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can simplify it a lot, there is no input file so flying blind...

Assuming the columns in interest are consecutive and fields are all numerical, just provide the start address

```
$ awk -F, -v s=79 'BEGIN {OFS=FS}
                   NR==1 {$(NF+1)="Header"}
                   NR >1 {v1=$s; v2=$(s+1); v3=$(s+2)
                          if(!v2 && !v3) $(NF+1) = v1?10:0
                          else $(NF+1) = v3?(v1-v3)/v3:0 + v2?(v1-v2)/v2:0}1' file
```

The parametric column names can be written as

```
$ cols="c1,c2,c3"; header="Header"
$ awk -F, -v cols="$cols" -v hdr="$header" '
           BEGIN {OFS=FS}
           NR==1 {n=split(cols,cn); 
                  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) 
                    for(j=1;j<=n;j++) 
                      if($i==cn[j]) c[++k]=i; 
                  $(NF+1)=hdr}
           NR >1 {v1=$c[1]; v2=$c[2]; v3=$c[3]
                  if(!v2 && !v3) $(NF+1) = v1?10:0
                  else $(NF+1) = v3?(v1-v3)/v3:0 + v2?(v1-v2)/v2:0}1' file

id,c1,c2,c3,Header
1,0,0,0,0
2,0,0,1,-1
3,0,1,0,-1
4,0,1,1,-1
5,1,0,0,10
6,1,0,1,0
7,1,1,0,0
8,1,1,1,0
```

for the given input file

```
id,c1,c2,c3
1,0,0,0
2,0,0,1
3,0,1,0
4,0,1,1
5,1,0,0
6,1,0,1
7,1,1,0
8,1,1,1
```

**Explanation**

`n=split(cols,cn)` splits the string "cols" into array "cn" using the same FS delimiter.  The number of elements will be returned and assigned to "n".

`1` is shorthand for `{print}`

Comment: give me some time to provide the sample input file

Comment: Have updated the question with sample input and output files. Please have a look at it and provide a solution accordingly.

Comment: as for ur solution, please note that my awk script  is required to be a function that is going to be called dynamically with parameters being the coloumn names and not the coloumn index.

Comment: So, test the `awk` script that replaces yours. If it works, wrap with in a bash script with standard parameter passing.  Change "Header" to another `awk` variable as I did above for start column "s"..

Comment: To my understanding, ur script is just a simplified version of my own script. Kindly go through My Requirement again.

Comment: Can u please take time to elaborate. I'm very new to AWK and have no idea about bash scripts.

Comment: Also please put it up as an answer so that i can mark it as correct, if i'm getting the required output.

Comment: see the updated script running with a made up test input.

Comment: When i feed the input file to your script, the new coloumn generates 0 for some rows where infact the value should be 10(which i get when i feed the input file to my awk script). Please help

Comment: I have another query, what if i have to call the above function n number of times with different parameters  being taken from the same input file? i have updated the requirement in the question. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: And yes the above answer is just what i wanted. The above query is just for extra knowledge. Thanks a lot for helping.

Comment: i was reviewing the answer u provided a while back. I just couldn't understand how u were using the cn variable in the line `n=split(cols,cn);`

Comment: I couldn't see where u were initializing cn. Also at the end last line `.........v2?(v1-v2)/v2:0}1' file` you put a `1` after  `}`. Could you please explain to me the logic here?

Answer (score 0):

```
# --- for your sample test ----------
column_1=1;column_2=2;column_3=3;new_header="Header"
```

## --- the generic code ------

```
awk -v Col1=${column_1} -v Col2=${column_2} -v Col3=${column_3} -v NewH="${new_header}" -F ',' '
  BEGIN { OFS = FS }
  FNR == 1 {
     $(NF + 1) = NewH
     print $0
     next
     }
  {
   if      ( ! $Col1 && ! $Col2 && ! $Col3) NewV = 0
   else if ( ! $Col2 && $Col3 )             NewV = ($Col1-$Col3)/$Col3
   else if ( ! $Col3 && $Col2 )             NewV = ($Col1-$Col2)/$Col2
   else if ( ! $Col3 && ! $Col2 && $Col1 )  NewV = 10
   else if ( $Col3 && $Col2)                NewV = (($Col1-$Col2)/$Col2)+(($Col2-$Col3)/$Col3)
   print $0
   }' YourFile
```

- pass value to variable via the -v argument of awk (integer is asis, string are quoted (see NewH)
- `var == 0` is the same a as `! var` in the if (you can keep your version for more readibility)
- no need of `;` at end of the line (this is a instruction separator for onliner)

you can catch directly the argument in awk but a bit heavier compare to calling awk with -v)

Comment: Finding an error: Coloumn name new_header is not being appended at the end of the first row.

Comment: also inside the awk script, is it $ColH1 or just ColH1

Comment: Its ColH1 got it. But still the new-header is not being displayed

Comment: Just so that we r on the same page here: new_header is a new coloumn that is being appended to the existing file which is storing all the results obtained in the function. The new content thus obtained has to be exported to an output file.

Comment: The computation being performed is also wrong. When i feed the input to this script the result obtained is different compared to the output being obtained by my awk script

Comment: Kindly suggest a revised solution

Comment: Provided a sample of my input file above

Comment: added the OFS=FS to keep same separator in output, removed the $ (sorry for that)

Comment: without `$` reference you're not referring the field values but just the defined column index, which will be constant.

Comment: Resulting new coloumn(header and its values) is not being appended to the input file.

Comment: Give me some time to provide a sample of the input file

Comment: @NeronLeVelu, Have updated the question with sample input and output files. Please have a look at it and provide a solution accordingly.

Comment: A quick test with the revisited code using your sample data works here on my linux.